# Passing results via promise chain not accessible?

Tags: javascript

According to my code below i am chaining all the data until the end where i wish to render the data to the view however using the .catch i found that summoner is not accessible at the final function.

```
getSummonerData(req.params.playerName)
.then(function(summoner) {
  return getMatchIds(summoner[0].id);
})
.then(function(matchIds) {
  return getGameData(matchIds);
})
.then(function(gameData) {
  res.render('profile', {player:summoner, games:gameData});
})
.catch(function(e) {
  console.log(e);
});
```

Comment: Just to confirm i am return promise in all promise functions

Comment: To be more accurate, as you're chaining, you need to pass the right `data shape` as resolved value, the summoner needs to be a prop of gameData in your case.

Comment: @Xlee: What do you mean by "data shape"? You can return anything you want from a `then` callback; `.then(function() { return 42; })` is just fine. If what you return is thenable, the promise `then` returns is slaved to that thenable. If what you return isn't thenable, the promise `then` returns is automatically resolved with the value you returned. `.then(function() { return Promise.resolve(x); })` (your now-deleted suggestion) is just a long way to write `.then(function() { return x; })`.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder do you think the returned promise of `getMatchIds(summoner[0].id)` resolved the value of summoner, as his err comes from summoner not defined?

Comment: @Xlee: I don't understand your question. But the OP said `summoner` was undefined in the `catch` handler at the end: *"...however using the .catch i found that summoner is not accessible at the final function."* `getMatchIds` isn't in the `catch` handler. (He/she hasn't shown trying to use it there, which makes it not hyper clear, but the text is clear about it.)

Comment: @T.J. Crowder I just mean `summoner` is being accessed in `res.render('profile', {player:summoner, games:gameData});` while it seems its value isn't passed down from the Promise chain

Comment: @Xlee: Ah, now that's a good observation, and it changes my understanding of the OP's sentence that I quoted above (and my answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, `summoner` is only accessible to the `then` callback containing your call to `getMatchIds`, not elsewhere. To be accessible later, you'd have to either 1) Return it from that `then` callback along with the game data, or 2) Nest the `then` callbacks that need it *inside* that callback.

The latter is probably the easier one:

```
getSummonerData(req.params.playerName)
.then(function(summoner) {
  return getMatchIds(summoner[0].id)
    .then(function(matchIds) {
      return getGameData(matchIds);
    })
    .then(function(gameData) {
      res.render('profile', {player:summoner, games:gameData});
    });
})
.catch(function(e) {
  console.log(e);
});
```

Comment: 's so just to confirm will that also pass gamedata to my render? Cheers it makes sense

Comment: @Elevant: Yes, that part is unaffected. By moving those handlers into the handler for `getSummonerData`, we let them close over `summoner`, but what they get from `getGameData` is unaffected.

Comment: Thanks mate, i am still learning how javascript callbacks function like access scope etc and just learning promises now as well haha :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by "promise function".  I am guessing you are not aware that 'then' and 'catch' always return promises.  That is why you can chain them.  Each 'then' or 'catch' is a method of the promise returned by its predecessor. Those chained promises are later resolved or rejected depending on what happens to their predecessors.

I assume your last function 'res.render(...)' returns the value you want to see.  Then the promise 'then(render(...))' will become resolved with the value received from 'res.render(...)'.

So that is what 'catch' will be working with:  a resolved promise with the value you want to see.  But 'catch' only fires its function with a 'rejected' promise.  You need a 'then' instead.